# jQuery Gallery, adding A HREF attribute to images?

Tags: jquery, html, image, gallery, href

I recently downloaded a jQuery Gallery for use on a website. Everything works fine, but I want the images shown in the gallery to be links to other (higher quality) images. Here is the code for the gallery featured on my website, www.mindsparkdesigns.com

```
(function($){
var settings = {
    width: 940,
    height: 252,
    thumbWidth: 50,
    thumbHeight: 50,
    thumbOpacity: 0.4,
    thumbHoverOpacity: 1,
    displayAlt: true
}

$.uGallery = function(userSettings){
    var images = [];
    $.extend(settings, userSettings);
    // parse input structure to images
    $("ul.gal>li>img").each(function(index, element){
        images[index] = $(element)
            .css({width: element.width+"px", height: element.height+"px"})
            .attr("a href", $(element).attr("a href"))
            .attr("src", $(element).attr("src"))
            .attr("alt", $(element).attr("alt"));

    });
    // recreate gallery structure using divs
    $("ul.gal").replaceWith("<div class='gal'><div class='gal-thumbs'></div><div class='gal-main-viewer'></div></div>");
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){ // fill it with images
        $("div.gal-thumbs").append(makeThumb(images[i]));
    }
    $("div.gal-thumbs>img").wrap("<div class='gal-thumb'><div class='gal-thumb-padder'></div></div>");
    // display the first thumb image in main viewer
    $("div.gal-thumbs>div.gal-thumb>div.gal-thumb-padder:first>img").trigger('click');
    // style the gallery
    setupCSS(images);
    // fade thumbs to the initial state
    $("div.gal-thumb-padder>img").fadeTo("slow", settings.thumbOpacity);
    // add thumb highlight onmouseover behaviour
    $("div.gal-thumb-padder>img").hover(
        function(){ $(this).fadeTo("fast", settings.thumbHoverOpacity); }, 
        function(){ $(this).fadeTo("slow", settings.thumbOpacity); }
    );
}

/**
 * creates proportionally resized image with onclick showing full image in image viewer
 */
makeThumb = function(img){
    var image = $("<img src='"+$(img).attr("src")+"' alt='"+$(img).attr("alt")+"' />");
    image.css({width: "127px", height: "50px" });
    image.css({msInterpolationMode: "bicubic"}); // smooth out thumbs in IE7
    image.bind("click", img, function(e){
        var image = $("<img src='"+$(img).attr("src")+"' alt='"+$(img).attr("alt")+"'  />");
        //image.css(proportionalDimensions(img, {x: settings.width - 20, y: settings.height - 20}));
        var alt = $("<div class='gal-alt'>"+$(img).attr("alt")+"</div>");
        alt.css({
            clear: "both", 
            width: 640 +"px", 
            padding: "10px", 
            "background-color": "black", 
            "margin": "auto",
            color: "white",
            textAlign: "left"
        });
        alt.fadeTo("fast", 0.75);
        $("div.gal-main-viewer").fadeOut("slow", function(){
            $(this).html(image).hide().fadeIn("slow").append(alt);
            if(settings.displayAlt){
                $("div.gal-alt").animate({marginTop: "-47px"}, 600);
            }
        });
    });
    return image;
}


/**
 * style the gallery
 */
setupCSS = function(images){
    $("div.gal-thumb").css({
        float: "left", 
        width: settings.thumbWidth+"px", 
        height: settings.thumbHeight+"px", 
        "text-align": "center", 
        "margin": "5px 5px 0px 0px",
        border: "1px solid #343434",
        padding: "5px",
        overflow: "hidden"
    });

    $("div.gal-thumb-padder").css({
        margin: "auto",
        width: settings.thumbWidth-5+"px",
        height: settings.thumbHeight-2+"px",
        overflow: "hidden"
    });

    $("div.gal").css({
        width: "940px",
        overflow: "hidden",
        marginLeft: "30px",
        marginTop: "10px"
    });

    $("div.gal-main-viewer").css({
        width: "640px", 
        height: "252px", 
        "text-align": "center",
        overflow: "hidden",
        margin: "auto",
        float: "right",
        border: "3px solid #141414",
        marginTop: "5px"
    });

    $("div.gal-thumbs-wrapper").css({
        width: settings.width-20+"px", 
        margin: "auto", 
        overflow: "hidden",
        "padding-top": "5px",
        "padding-bottom": "10px"
    });

    $("div.gal-thumbs").css({ 
        width: "240px",
        height: "260px",
        overflow: "auto",
        float: "left",
    });

    $("div.gal-thumb>img").css("background-color", "black");
}
})(jQuery)
```

Now the html code for the gallery div:

```
     <div id="gall">
    <p class="gallery-name">Portfolio</p>
    <ul class="gal">
        <li><a href="images/gowang-logo-big.jpg"><img src="images/gowang-logo.jpg" class="gal-image" title="Logo for Gowang Adventures" alt="Logo design for the Gowang Adventures video game"/></a></li>
        <li><img src="images/gowang.jpg" class="gal-image" title="Gowang Adventures Box Art" alt="A concept video-game box art for Gowang Adventures"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/magical.jpg" class"gal-image" title="Magical" alt="Personal logo for a Video Game Box Artist"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/roaring.jpg" class"gal-image" title="Roaring Arts" alt="Logo design for an online art event"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/zelda.jpg" class"gal-image" title="Zelda Treasure Scroll" alt="Concept video game logo for personal project"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/eyeronic-logo.jpg" class="gal-image" title="Eyeronic Surf Team logo" alt="Logo for Eyeronic Surf Team"/></li>       
        <li><img src="images/mycheal-logo.jpg" class="gal-image" title="Mycheal McQureerirais" alt="Personal logo for Game Designer Mycheal McQureerirais"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/mycheal-card.jpg" class="gal-image" title="Mycheal McQureerirais" alt="Business Card for Game Designer Mycheal McQureerirais"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/girard-logo.jpg" class="gal-image" title="Girard Home Interiors" alt="Company logo for Girard Custom Home Interiors"/></li>  
    </ul>

    </div>
```

The first link I added an `a href` to just to show you where I want the images to link. Each image should link to a different image.

Now I tried adding an `a href` attribute to the images in the list, as shown here:

http://www.h-3.abload.de/img/1qe2s.png

When I do that, the images link to other images, just like I want them too, but the gallery is destroyed.

Before: http://www.h-3.abload.de/img/3dg4n.png

After: http://wwwh-3.abload.de/img/2ce8p.png

I'm sure there is a way to do this right, but my jQuery knowledge is basic, so i'm not sure how. Any help would be greatly appreciated! If you need any more info, just ask.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I edited your question to change the faux-links into real links on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

This works (but, frankly, I'm ashamed of it, given the clunkiness of the string manipulations):

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
       $('ul.gal > li > img')
           .each(
               function(){
                   var biggerSrc = $(this).attr('src'),
                       biggerSrcLength = biggerSrc.length
                       biggerHref = biggerSrc.substring(0,biggerSrcLength - 4) + '-big.jpg';
                   $(this)
                       .wrap('<a class="biggerImg" href="'+ biggerHref +'"></a>');
               });
        $('a.biggerImg').live('click',
            function(){
               // handles the click event for dynamically-added a elements.
            });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/K9jVc/1/).

Comment: Thank you for replying, and for your edit. Unfortunately I can't seem to get this to work. Where excatly does this block of code go, and do I still add the A HREF to the images on the list? Or will it automatically go to the "-big" version of the image?

Comment: This should probably go after whatever gallery plugin you're using has finished manipulating the images/links. This script just looks at those images that are directly descended from the `li` children of `ul.gal` and wraps them in an `a` (link) that links to the bigger image.

Comment: Hmm, I placed it where you said, and after refreshing the page, the images are all gone. Am I doing something wrong? (http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/2381/20256426.png) (http://img176.imageshack.us/img176/9761/79474917.png)

Comment: Ah, I didnt realize you changed the code. This newer version seems to screw up the cycle plugin on my page: http://img530.imageshack.us/img530/4914/24817845.png If you want, I can send you the files, so you can work things out for yourself.